# EntityFramework LEFT OUTER JOIN в CodeFirst

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Создаю для обучения и понятие `Entity Framework`, тестовое приложение.
Выбрал как все советают, `CodeFirst`.

Прочитал про `one-to-one relationship`, `one-to-many` и тд, на этом примере (one-to-one):

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }
}
     
public class StudentAddress 
{
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Первое, что мне не понятно, какой столбец указывает на какой.
Второе, хотелось бы понять, как такой `SQL` запрос, перевести в `EntityFramework CodeFirst`:

```
    SELECT
    dbo.Table1.Group
  , dbo.Table1.Number
  , dbo.Table1.Start
  , dbo.Table1.Prio
  , dbo.Table1.Comment
  , dbo.Table2.FloatNumber
FROM
    dbo.Table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.Table2
        ON
            dbo.Table1.Number = dbo.Table2.Number
```

Comment: [Perform left outer joins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins). Для этого используется метод `DefaultIfEmpty`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, а есть тоже самое с Fluent API?

Comment: [Join](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-operators#join)